# Do I have to use an external power supply when connecting an ultrasonic sensor to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

This might be a very stupid question but please bear with me. So I am using an HC-SR04 Ultrasonic sensor model (5 V) and I want to connect it to Arduino Uno. Do I have to use an external power supply for the ultrasonic sensor (just like with the motors) in order to connect it to the Arduino? Or can I just use the 5 V pin?

Comment: It is a low current device so yes you can connect it to the 5V pin, also consult the datasheet for setup stuff and current draw.

Comment: http://www.spiked3.com/?p=6021 - includes code without using libraries for arrays of SR04s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question I assume you power your Arduino via USB in which case you don't need an external supply. The HC-SR04 draws 15 mA with is far below the specifications for USB. I did this myself some time ago:

[image]